# 0xc00007b error when launching Assassin's Creed: Black Flag?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I used to play games easily on my laptop, I bought a new laptop (a Lenovo E540) and I installed Windows 8.1, which is the same operating system as I had on the old one, and I ran through all of the system updates for drivers and DirectX.

I installed the same games on my new laptop (ex: Assassin's Creed IV - Black Flag) but a strange weird error displayed "Application Was Unable To Start Correctly (0xc00007b)" as follows:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: [According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx), `0xC000007B` is an error code with the meaning `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. There are a couple of reasons why this error can appear, but for a game, this usually means something is wrong with the executable file. Have you tried re-installing the game?

Comment: yes, even I got a different copy of the game, but the issue still the same???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution that worked for me was to reinstall Windows 8.1.

After deep investigation, I found that one of the DLLs for DirectX was corrupted.

I tried to update DirectX but it keep informing me that I had the latest version with no errors.

Comment: Maybe you could uninstall and reinstall DirectX?

Comment: this is not possible, there is no way to uninstall directx

Comment: Not even the redist?

Answer (score 3):

The error message `0xC000007B` typically indicates that the .NET Framework that the game was built with is not installed. A quick google search indicates that Black Flag requires the framework version 4.5.1. This *should* be installed with the game unless it was cancelled for some reason.

.NET Framwork 4.5.1 specifies the [following minimum system requirements](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40779):

> Supported Operating System
>
> Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1,
>   Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Vista
>   Service Pack 2  Hardware Requirements: •1 GHz or faster processor •512
>   MB of RAM  •850 MB of available hard disk space (x86) •2 GB of
>   available hard disk space (x64)

Comment: 4.5.1 is installed by default on Windows 8.1 it's literally not possible not to have it installed

Answer (score 1):

take the xinput1_3.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher and put it in c:\windows\system32 and it's all right.

Comment: Please take a moment to explain why this fixes things, and where you learned this.